Balance of Payment vs. FX rate
How can a country with a Current Account deficit can have an exchange rate appreciating and viceversa a Current Account surplus and a currency depreciating?

A country running a current account deficit is importing more than it is exporting. Hence, a current account deficit should cause the value of the domestic currency to fall. This will make exports cheaper and imports more expensive, balancing the current account.

there are many examples of countries with CA deficit and FX appreciating , see just the US post covid with a stronger USD

True. In fact, the U.S. has not run a current account surplus since about the 1980s, with a single spike during the 1990s.  https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/current-account
